# How to hide sensitive URL from page source

Tags: security, html

We have a website which integrates with third party URLs via iframe. We really don't want our users to be able to see if they are seeing content from iframe. This is for the reason that we don't want any one else to be able to use the iframe link directly or integrate to their own page. Also we can not apply security on iframe link, as it is from third party vendor.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible to hide the real URL if you need to include it.

Which I can suggest you is to use [Sandboxed Iframes](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) 
And craft a good [CSP Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/)

By the use of the CSP you can prevent an external site load untrusted content on your web.